# Change html hierarchy using jquery for mobile layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hierarchy

I'm creating a responsive website and the menus for the tablet and mobile layouts need to be different then the pc layout. So my client wants his logo coming first to the tablet/mobile layout, i tried to use jquery but is not working, can someone help me?
I need the li fot the logo be the first when the window width is lesser then 1024px, but my jquery is not working.

html:

```
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img class="lupa" src="img/lupa.png" alt="Search" onClick="ShowFieldSearch()"></a>
                  <div id="boxSearch">
                        <form id="formSearch" action="" method="get">
                            <input id="search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" placeholder="Search..." onBlur="HideFieldSearch()">
                        </form>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products<img class="flechaVertical" src="img/flecha.png" alt="flecha"></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img id="navLogo" class="navLogo" src="img/logotipo.png" alt="Versatyll"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contats</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Doubts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
            #boxSearch{
    padding-left:15px;  
}

#Search{
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:10px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #222222;   
}

/* -------------------------------*/

/* Navigation Menus */

.lupa{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-left:35px;  
}

.flechaVertical{
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    padding-left:5px;   
}

.navLogo{
    width:160px;
    height:90px;    
}

.nav{
    width:200px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
}

.nav ul{    
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
}

.nav ul li{
    display:block;
}

.nav ul li a,visited{
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#990000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
         var $logo = $(".nav ul li").eq(3);
         function PositionLogo(){
           if($(window).width() < 1024){
             $logo.remove().insertBefore(".nav ul li:first-chiild");
           }
           else{
             $logo.remove().insertAfter(".nav ul li:nth-child(3));
           }
         }
        });
```

Comment: You need to remove that extra i for the first child and add a " after child(3) just to clean your jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better option but this works as well :

Your jQuery needs to be cleaned too.

**HTML**

```
<li class="logo">
  <a href="#"><img id="navLogo" class="navLogo" src="img/logotipo.png" alt="Versatyll"></a>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($(window).width() + "doc");
  var $logo = $(".logo");
  if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
     $logo.remove();
     $(".nav ul li:first-child").append($logo)
  }
});
```

since you're firing it on document ready i dont think you need the else condition.

Also, your code wouldn't change the position if the window is resized.

Also, I think its better to fire it.

```
$(window).load(function() {

// your code

});
```

and here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72cy1bdt/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need this small change just skip Jquery and use CSS Media Queries to hide and display a logo

for desktop and one for mobile using ids.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PatoSalazarC/014khzmd/) (resize the results block). It will change at 800px in this case so you can see the results on the fiddle.

First add this line in your head for responsiveness

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="logo_nav">Logo Nav</li>
        <li><a href="#"><img class="lupa" src="img/lupa.png" alt="Search" onClick="ShowFieldSearch()"></a>
          <div id="boxSearch">
                <form id="formSearch" action="" method="get">
                    <input id="search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" placeholder="Search..." onBlur="HideFieldSearch()">
                </form>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products<img class="flechaVertical" src="img/flecha.png" alt="flecha"></a>
        </li>
        <li id="logo_desktop"> logo Desktop</li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doubts</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#logo_nav{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #logo_desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    #logo_nav {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This should work